# How to edit iOS system file on my iPad over SSH?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, ipad

I have an iPad with iOS 7.1.1. I jailbroke it and was able to ssh it from wifi without a problem.

Lately I wanted to edit some system files to tweak few settings but I realized that there is no vi (or any other file editor) in the file system. Is there anyway I can install 'ios version of vi' or any other file editor?

I don't want to install independent app for it (such as iFile)—I need an editor which works in shell.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install vim`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install nano or vi from Saurik's repo.